# Importing jar files in neabeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I've been used to simply importing jar files into my netbeans projects and then being able to import them in my projects. For example, I included the guava.jar. I saw it under libraries and when I expanded it, I saw things like com.google.common.*. So, I just said import com.google.common.* in my own classes and I was able to use their methods. Similarly for commons-math3-3.0.jar. But now I similarly included joptimizer-3.2.0-sources.jar (http://www.joptimizer.com/usage.html). When I expand it, I see folders like "src.main.com.joptimizer.functions" However, this time when I go to my projects and try to say import src.main..., it doesn't work they are not recognized. Why did simply importing the jars work before, but not in this case? And what do I need to do in this case to be able to use the methods in the joptimizer jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included **sources** to you project. **Sources** means jar with not compiled ***.java** files.
You should add jar with compiled java classes (***.class** files).

Looks like there is no compiled library on http://www.joptimizer.com/usage.html site
and you should compile it manually.

Install **maven** tool, unpack `joptimizer-3.2.0-sources.jar` and execute

```
mvn package
```

in the root directory (directory with `pom.xml`)
You will find compiled library in `target` directory

Comment: I tried this.. maven fails at the last minute saying it couldn't resolve the dependency.. could not find artifact seventytwomiles:architecture-rules:jar:3.0.0-M1 in central repo - <http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 ..

I have a feeling I might need to change some thing in the pom.xml file for this to work, but have no idea what. Googling for this missing dependency led me no where.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. since I am in a hurry to make this work, I will post this additional glitch as a second question.